# Is there a quick way to stage change hunks shown by vim-signify without entering a diff mode?

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive

I'm using [vim-signify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-signify) to see what changes exist in sources managed by git.  I'd like to be able to easily stage those hunks, without having to open a separate diff view between the working copy and the index (as provided by [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)'s `:Gdiff`)…after all, I'm *already* looking at a diff in a sense!

(The same question would apply to anyone using a git/svn/hg/whatever gutter plugin, including [vim-gitgutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) and similar.)

Concretely, I guess I'm looking for the equivalent of fugitive's `:Gwrite`, if `:Gwrite` could take a range.

Comment: FYI, I've filed a feature request on vim-fugitive to help support this: https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/370

Answer (score 4):

[vim-gitgutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) now lets you stage/undo individual hunks with `<Leader>hs` and `<Leader>hu` (those mappings are configurable).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! `<Leader>hr` does not seem to work to undo a hunk, `<Leader>hu` works.

Comment: Ah, the default mapping was [changed](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter/commit/b3db866aab59961303e6cf6174b719b551d4d00c) on 21 April 2016.

Comment: Indeed, they reworded it from `revert` to `undo`. You may want to update your answer. Thanks again Andy!

Comment: Aha, I didn't realise I could update my answer after all this time :)